# Swimmer's elbow problems

Tags: technique, swimming, injuries

In the last year I have been, on and off, troubled by what I believe is *swimmer's elbow*.

The pain does not prevent me from swimming but it is affecting my ability to pull with maximum force in the front & back crawl and especially the butterfly, which I have found to be the stroke that aggravates it the most.

The majority of the pain exists just behind and in front of the elbow, as if it's the tendons or something (I'm not a physio so this is my best description).

The pain does linger during the day and can affect some actions eg. I wince sometimes when putting on or taking off a t-shirt, but I wouldn't describe it as disabling.

So my questions are:

- is this something I can avoid, perhaps by strengthening muscles further up the arm and, if so, what would they be?
- is there anything I can do when I have the pain, to get rid of it?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: talk to a doctor, not the Internet.

Comment: @Philip Doctors are not necessarily swimmers. I'm after some opinions from people who have experienced it and have seen improvement (or not). if it's a technique issue, how is a doctor going to advise?